# Sync Framework, filter fake deleted rows

Tags: c#, sql, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

Context:
I want to synchronize Sql Server to Sql Compact trough wcf. The client (sqlce) only downloads updates from the server(sql2008) from time to time. On the server nothing gets ever deleted it's only marked as "deleted" (more specifically Version == MinValue means it's deleted),

Problem:
I don't want my clients to have deleted items in their db. 
When an item that is both on server and client, but then is marked as deleted (Version=MinValue) i want this item to be completely deleted from client not just marked

Do you think this scenarios is possible with sync framework and filters ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup filters in the WCF service.

Unfortunately, I cannot recall the details.

Comment: i don't think WCF will help me here.. since the sync framework will always sync the deleted

Comment: @Zapacila: I have dont exactly this about 3 years ago. It works, and it works that way.

Comment: For this approach you need to implement your own SyncAdapters with filtering commands and then it does also work...

Comment: @chrfin: You can just extend the generated code, IIRC, it was not much.

Answer (score 0):

The Sync-Framework use Tombstone-Tables for that:
In the SyncAdapter you can define a tombstone-Table and deleted row should be moved to that table, which means they are still available (and the "delete" can be synced easily), but not in the "main-table" anymore.

Comment: sync framework dont move rows to the tombstone tables, it simply stores the pk of the deleted row since only the pk is required to delete the row in the destination.

Comment: @JuneT: I think he meant on the client side and there they are deleted. On the server side you can e.g. implement a delete trigger to add/update the tombstone record on deletion.

Comment: even on client side. sync framework never copies the row. of what use are all the columns of a row if all you need to delete a row is the PK?

Answer (score 0):

if you're just doing soft deletes by marking the rows as deleted, these will be cascaded as updates to your clients.

in your client, just delete all rows that has been marked for deletion and clear the tombstone tables yourself. without any record in the tombstone table, these deleted rows will not be picked up by Sync Framework.

Another options for you is on the client, delete the rows marked for deletion, subscribe to the ChangesSelected event of the client provider, and manually loop thru the change dataset to remove the deleted rows in the datatable.

or you can also intercept these rows in the ChangesSelected event of the server provider. you'll have to loop thru the change dataset and the corresponding datatable, find all rows that has the deleted flag and mark that rows as deleted. they will be applied as deleted in the destination.

see sample here: http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2011/03/07/manipulating-the-change-dataset-in-sync-fx/